# How can i compare and merge two array

Tags: php, arrays

I have following two arrays which comes from the same database use the same query to get both. both contains information about a single sales order having two different line items(Bill of materials) the first one has Line Item`ItemID= 600271` and the second one has LineItem `ItemID=600274` but as you can see below they both have the same Sales Order Number `[CustomerSONo] => [7] => **15020**`

so How can i compare or union these two array's. ?

//query

```
    $result= --select statement--;
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
        print_r($row);
     }
```

Array 1

```
     Array ( 
           [0] => XXX001 
           [CustomerId] => XXX001 
           [1] => XXX Company Name.*
           [Customer_Bill_Name] => XXX Company Name.* 
           [2] => DHE 
           [WhichShipVia] => DHE [3] => 
           [INV_POSOOrderNumber] => [4] => 2014-12-19 
           [ShipByDate] => 2014-12-19 [5] => 
           [GoodThruDate] => [6] => 
           [CustomerSONo] => [7] => 15020 
           [Reference] => 15020 [8] => 2014-11-25 
           [TransactionDate] => 2014-11-25 [9] => 1 
           [DistNumber] => 1 
           [10] => 70.0000000000000000000 //here is the difference 1
           [Quantity] => 70.0000000000000000000  //here is the difference 2
           [11] => 600271  //here is the difference 3
           [ItemId] => 600271 //here is the difference 4
           [12] => ASSY7.60-15SL/8 FRM I1 15X6 6-6, BLK (GWT-761508 (24) //here is the difference 5
           [SalesDescription] => ASSY7.60-15SL/8 FRM I1 15X6 6-6, BLK (GWT-761508)(24)//here is the difference 1 //here is the difference 6
           [13] => AS1577 //here is the difference 7
           [PartNumber] => AS1577 //here is the difference 8
           [14] => ASSY7.60-15 8PLY W/WHL15X6 BLK //here is the difference 9
           [ItemDescription] => ASSY7.60-15 8PLY W/WHL15X6 BLK )
```

Array 2:

```
     Array ( 
            [0] => XXX001 
            [CustomerId] => XXX001 
            [1] => XXX Company Name.*
            [Customer_Bill_Name] => XXX Company Name.* 
            [2] => DHE [WhichShipVia] => DHE [3] =>
            [INV_POSOOrderNumber] =>   [4] => 2014-12-19 
            [ShipByDate] => 2014-12-19  [5] => 
            [GoodThruDate] => [6] => 
            [CustomerSONo] => [7] => 15020 
            [Reference] => 15020 [8] => 2014-11-25 
            [TransactionDate] => 2014-11-25 [9] => 2 
            [DistNumber] => 2 
            [10] => 6.0000000000000000000 //here is the difference 1
            [Quantity] => 6.0000000000000000000 //here is the difference 2
            [11] => 600274  //here is the difference 3
            [ItemId] => 600274 //here is the difference 4
            [12] => ASSY9.5L-15SL/8 FLT I1 15X8 6-6, BLK (GWT-951508)(16)      
            [SalesDescription] => ASSY9.5L-15SL/8 FLT I1 15X8 6-6, BLK (GWT-951508)(16) //here is the difference 5
            [13] => AS1601 //here is the difference 6
            [PartNumber] => AS1601 //here is the difference 7
            [14] => ASSY9.5L-15 W/WHL15X8 6/6 BLK //here is the difference 8
            [ItemDescription] => ASSY9.5L-15 W/WHL15X8 6/6 BLK ) //here is the difference 9
```

Comment: You start by defining how that union would look like. I have no idea how you want the end result to be ;)

Comment: [check out this link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26874385/create-an-array-with-a-key-if-values-exists-in-two-arrays) its a question I posted and I posted the answer myself

Comment: [`array_intersect_key`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-intersect-key.php).

Comment: I posted the real link sorry, check it out. Hope it helps

Comment: @NielsKeurentjes how can i manage the comparison using for each

Comment: you may want to check out the difference between `mysqli_fetch_array` and `mysqli_fetch_assoc`. having your data organized in a sane fashion helps.

Comment: You need to use KEYS and loop through both array and find the matching values. When matched then create a new array.

Comment: @alda1234 they both in same array `$row`how can i handle the loop to compare the two arrays?

Comment: @KinfeGebreselassie did you look at the link I posted? Everything is explained and the answer is easy to understand

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Option 1

```
$orders = array();

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    $orders[$row['CustomerSONo'][] = $row;
}
```

This will add all rows that share the same CustomerSONo together in one array. If you have multiple orders, you can get all the seperate orders using

```
foreach($orders as $orderNo => $order) {
    foreach($order as $key => $orderRow) {

    }
}
```

## Option 2

If you however only want to extract the ItemIDs from each order, you can do the following:

```
$orderItems = array();
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    $orderItems[$row['CustomerSONo']][] = $row['ItemID'];
}
```

This will create an array called `$orderItems` that only stores the order numbers in the array, rather than all the information about the order.

## Option 3

If you want to echo the lines, you first have to "sort" them like in Option 2. Once you have gained all `ItemID`s that belong to one `CustomerSONo`, you do another foreach loop to echo them into a single line.

```
foreach($orders as $orderNo => $itemIds) {
    echo "Order #" . $orderNo . ": " . implode(", ", $itemIds);
}
```

This will create the following:

`Order #1: 18340, 1837, 13`
`Order #2: 183, 868, 285, 860`

Comment: He does not want all comparisons of the array keys. He's only interested in all the arrays where the CustomerSONo matches, so he can group these together. My method produces one array with all orders that he retrieves from MySQL, which he can easily search through. I don't really see what the problem with this code would be. Using the function you mentioned in your reply to his original question, PHP will compare all indices, while he only wants one to match. I think that's unnecessary work.

Comment: thanks Ruben i dont understand this line  $orders[$value['CustomerSONo'][] = $row;` and how can i extract the two LineItem `ItemID=600274` and `ItemID=600271`

Comment: Oh my bad, I made a mistake when editing my code there. `$value` should have been `$row`. Right now, when you retrieve one row from MySQL, it will contain an index 'CustomerSONo', which is what you want to group. Do you want to just get the ItemIDs, or do you want to group the order rows together? In that case, see option 2 in my answer.

Comment: Hi Ruben I want to group the orders and extract the two Line items then display on the same line like CustomerSONo =15020 | Line item1 = 600274 | Lineitem2=600271 on in one line thanks!!

Comment: @Kinfe So you want to just print the values?

Comment: yes and then i am going to add the record into 3rd party app as a single record using API. thanks for the quick reply

Comment: Check my latest option.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/65658/discussion-between-ruben-rutten-and-kinfe-gebreselassie).